# Binding click event to new element & making ID's unique

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've built this page:

http://www.rawlinspaints.com/development/form2.html

But when you add a new product the "product" dropdown no longer works.

I'm told this is because i need to add a "click event" to the new element and make sure the new elements are unique in terms of ID. I'm not a programmer so could really do with some pointers!

Any help much appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#product").change(function () {
     var selected = $("#product option:selected").val();
     $('div').hide();
     $('#' + selected).show();

 });
 $('div').hide();
 });
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){


$(function () {
$('table').on('click', 'tr a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});

$("#addTableRow").click(function() {
    $("#mans").each(function () {
        var tds = '<tr>';
        jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
            tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
        });
        tds += '</tr>';
        if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
            $('tbody', this).append(tds);
        } else {
            $(this).append(tds);
        }
    });
});
});


}//]]>  

</script>

<style type="text/css">
body,th {
font-size: 14px;
font-weight:bold;
color: #000;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
td{
    background-color:#ebebeb;
border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
}
input,select {border-radius:6px;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px;}
img{float:right;margin-top: -141px;
margin-left: -67px;
margin-right: 26px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" id="mans">
    <tr>
        <td>
         Product: <select id="product">
<option value="0">Select a Product</option>
<option value="1">Stair Nosing</option>
<option value="2">Stair Tread Covers</option>
<option value="3">Landing Covers</option>
<option value="4">Flat Plate</option>
<option value="5">50mm Convex Decking Strips</option>
<option value="6">100mm Convex Decking Strips</option>
<option value="7">Fixings</option>
</select>
<div id="1">
Quantity: <input name="Quantity" type="text" value=""></br>
Colour:
<select id="StairNosingColour">
<option value="Colour">Select a Colour</option>
<option value="1">Yellow</option>
<option value="2">Black</option>
<option value="3">White</option>
<option value="4">Luminous</option>
</select></br>
Size:
<select id="StairNosingSize">
<option value="Size">Select a Size</option>
<option value="1">750mm Length (L to R) x 55mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="2">1000mm Length (L to R) x 55mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="3">1500mm Length (L to R) x 55mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="4">2000mm Length (L to R) x 55mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="4">2500mm Length (L to R) x 55mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="4">3000mm Length (L to R) x 55mm Depth (going)</option>
</select></br>
Cutting & Drilling Instructions:
<input name="Cutting &amp; Drilling Instructions" type="text" value="Length/Pre Drilled Holes">
<img src="nosing.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="2">
Quantity: <input name="Quantity" type="text" value=""></br>
Colour:
<select id="StairTreadCoversColour">
<option value="Colour">Select a Colour</option>
<option value="1">Black with White Nosing</option>
<option value="2">Black with Yellow Nosing</option>
</select></br>
Size:
<select id="StairTreadCoversSize">
<option value="Size">Select a Size</option>
<option value="1">750mm Length (L to R) x 345mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="2">1000mm Length (L to R) x 345mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="3">1500mm Length (L to R) x 345mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="4">2000mm Length (L to R) x 345mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="4">2500mm Length (L to R) x 345mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="4">3000mm Length (L to R) x 345mm Depth (going)</option>
</select></br>
Cutting & Drilling Instructions:
<input name="Cutting &amp; Drilling Instructions" type="text" value="Length/Depth/Pre Drilled Holes">
<img src="stc.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="3">
Quantity: <input name="Quantity" type="text" value=""></br>
Colour:
<select id="LandingCoversColour">
<option value="Colour">Select a Colour</option>
<option value="1">Black with Yellow Nosing</option>
</select></br>
Size:
<select id="LandingCoversSize">
<option value="Size">Select a Size</option>
<option value="1">1220mm Length (L to R) x 1220mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="2">2440mm Length (L to R) x 1220mm Depth (going)</option>
</select></br>
Cutting & Drilling Instructions:
<input name="Cutting &amp; Drilling Instructions" type="text" value="Length/Depth/Pre Drilled Holes">
<img src="lc.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="4">
Quantity: <input name="Quantity" type="text" value=""></br>
Colour:
<select id="FlatPlateColour">
<option value="Colour">Select a Colour</option>
<option value="1">Black</option>
<option value="1">Yellow</option>
<option value="1">Beige</option>
<option value="1">Grey</option>
</select></br>
Size:
<select id="FlatPlateSize">
<option value="Size">Select a Size</option>
<option value="1">1220mm Length (L to R) x 1220mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="2">2000mm Length (L to R) x 1000mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="3">2440mm Length (L to R) x 1220mm Depth (going)</option>
</select></br>
Cutting & Drilling Instructions:
<input name="Cutting &amp; Drilling Instructions" type="text" value="Length/Depth/Pre Drilled     Holes">
<img src="fp.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="5">
Quantity: <input name="Quantity" type="text" value=""></br>
Colour:
<select id="50mmStripColour">
<option value="Colour">Select a Colour</option>
<option value="1">Black</option>
<option value="1">Yellow</option>
<option value="1">Beige</option>
</select></br>
Size:
<select id="50mmStripSize">
<option value="Size">Select a Size</option>
<option value="1">1000mm Length (L to R) x 50mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="2">1500mm Length (L to R) x 50mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="3">2000mm Length (L to R) x 50mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="4">3000mm Length (L to R) x 50mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="5">3600mm Length (L to R) x 50mm Depth (going)</option>
</select></br>
Cutting & Drilling Instructions:
<input name="Cutting &amp; Drilling Instructions" type="text" value="Length/Pre Drilled Holes">
<img src="ds.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="6">
Quantity: <input name="Quantity" type="text" value=""></br>
Colour:
<select id="100mmStripColour">
<option value="Colour">Select a Colour</option>
<option value="1">Black</option>
<option value="1">Yellow</option>
<option value="1">Beige</option>
</select></br>
Size:
<select id="100mmStripSize">
<option value="Size">Select a Size</option>
<option value="1">1000mm Length (L to R) x 100mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="2">1500mm Length (L to R) x 100mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="3">2000mm Length (L to R) x 100mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="4">3000mm Length (L to R) x 100mm Depth (going)</option>
<option value="5">3600mm Length (L to R) x 100mm Depth (going)</option>
</select></br>
Cutting & Drilling Instructions:
<input name="Cutting &amp; Drilling Instructions" type="text" value="Length/Pre Drilled Holes">
<img src="ds.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="" />
</div>
<div id="7">
Quantity: <input name="Quantity" type="text" value=""></br>
Size:
<select id="FixingSize">
<option value="Size">Select a Size</option>
<option value="1">SureStep Clear Adhesive 310ml Cartridge</option>
<option value="2">Box of 100 Self Drilling Screws M4.8 x 25mm</option>
<option value="3">Box of 100 Wood Screws & Plugs M4.8 x 35mm</option>
<option value="4">Square Plate, Nut & Bolt 45 x 45mm M8 x 35mm</option>
</select>
</div>

        </td>
                    <td><a href="#">Remove Product</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<button type="button" id="addTableRow">Add Another Product</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Got any code? I'm sure I know the fix, but we need code!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Why are you including jQuery twice? Also, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: I just added multiple products, everything works just fine.

Comment: Code added, and this is code ive been given but it doesnt work how it should do. Im not sure how to change from using ID to CLASS for new products added. Really need some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You got duplicate 'id' when you try to add new product. Use class instead of 'id' for this situation.

Comment: Sorry as i said im no programmer so not sure on how to make this work :(

Comment: I see. How did you create this solution? By tool?

Comment: I found these bits of code on jFiddle and managed to get it working to this stage, but problem now is that when new product is added the drop down stops working to change divs based on product selected. I'm now lost! :(

Comment: By using class instead of id you can solve this problem easily. Just like $('.className') instead of $('.currentId') ...etc. Sorry because you're not a programmer. :)

Comment: Ok, still lost but fair enough.